# How to aggregate array of struct column in pyspark without exploding

Tags: pyspark, nested

I would like to aggregate sum of Order.amount for each customerId `where date<='30/03/2021'(mm/dd/yyyy)`, taking advantage of having the array per userId rows.

output based on the below input data.

```
1 250
2 450

CustomerID    Order
1          [[1,100,01/01/2021],[2,200,06/01/2021],[3,150,03/01/2021]]                
2          [[1,200,02/01/2021],[2,250,03/01/2021],[3,300,05/01/2021]]

                                     

CustomerID
     array : Order
         struct of element
            Order
            amount
            date
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `'03/30/2021'`(MM/dd/yyyy)? also what spark version do you use?

Comment: '03/30/2021'(MM/dd/yyyy) and the spark 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `df` is your dataframe,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ((1, [[1,100,'01/01/2021'],[2,200,'06/01/2021'],[3,150,'03/01/2021']]),
     (2 , [[1,200,'02/01/2021'],[2,250,'03/01/2021'],[3,300,'05/01/2021']])),
     "CustomerID : int, Order : array<struct<Order: int, amount: int, date: string>>")

df.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- CustomerID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- Order: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- Order: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

for Spark version >= 2.4.x, you can use [higher order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/higher-order-functions-tutorial-python.html) to work with array. In this case, `filter` the dates then `aggregate` the amounts.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sql_expr = """  
    aggregate(
        filter(order, x -> to_date(x.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= '2021-03-30').amount,
        0, (a, b) -> a + b)
    """
df = df.withColumn('total_amount', F.expr(sql_expr))
df.show()

# +----------+--------------------+------------+
# |CustomerID|               Order|total_amount|
# +----------+--------------------+------------+
# |         1|[[1, 100, 01/01/2...|         250|
# |         2|[[1, 200, 02/01/2...|         450|
# +----------+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: This is working great. can it possible to use withColumn to add this Aggregated column with original dataframe.

Comment: Use `expr` function. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you AdibP it is working. sorry I am new to this pyspark. i have request how to pass data value "2021-03-30" from a variable and also add one more condition based on another column "status" in the Order array. For example along with date <= dt ('2021-03-30') and status = 'C'.

Comment: then add `and x.status = 'C'` inside the filter conditions